# Visual Studio Code - setting it up for multiple languages

Tags: python, c, visual-studio-code

I've just downloaded VSC, because I wanted to edit all my code in one editor (I'm writing in C, Python and HTML). On my computer I have a folder (Programming), in which I have 3 sub-folders (C, Python, HTML). So when I started up VSC I opened this Programming folder, and also downloaded the necessary extensions for python and C in VSC.
Here comes my problem: if I run for example a .py which generates a .txt file, it's not generated in the same location as the .py file is, however in the main folder (programming). Also this issue occurs, when I build an .exe from a .c, it also builds in the main folder and not where my .c is.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Change the directory in your terminal. (Ctrl + J should make it pop open)

Answer (score 0):

The default **cwd**(current working directory) is the folder you open, like you can see:

[image]

Even the `script_2.py` is under `VSCODE\Python\Too\b_folder`, its cwd is still under the folder `VSCODE` and not the specific project.

We can change cwd by the method `os.chdir()` in the file:

[image]

OR the second way, add `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,` in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

[image]

These are some workarounds, and it's still recommended that you turn to the specific project and go on development.

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution with settings.json works brilliantly. How can I use it for C programs as well?

Comment: It's not found in C/C++ features. You can turn to the project folder to code and this won't be a problem.